# Benchmarking File I/O under macOS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, file-io, instruments, appkit

I'm writing an application that reads in the metadata of thousands of images (JPEGs, RAW, etc...) and I'm trying to get a better understanding of its performance characteristics.

When the files are read from an SSD, then the performance is quite good. When files are read from an external, non-SSD drive then (obviously) performance is much worse. I'm struggling to accurately benchmark my application to get a better understanding of where the additional time is spent on non-SSD drives. (Other than "Well yeah, because the drive is slower.")

When I benchmark using Xcode Instruments' "Time Profiler" tool, none of the operating system's time spent dealing with the filesystem is reported. What is reported is time spent within my own application or libraries that it calls out to. On an SSD drive, this is meaningful because it tends to be more compute-bound. On an external drive, it's I/O-bound and thus the Instruments trace shows relatively low CPU usage for my application even though "a lot is happening" at the filesystem level.

There's an Instruments tool called "System Usage", but that is only for iOS. The "File Activity" tool shows what files are opened, but no performance metrics. What I'm curious to see is what part of the process is slowing things down and whether there are ways it can be improved.

**For example:**

- Am I accidentally stat'ing the file multiple times.
- Are multiple file paths being created when they shouldn't be.
- What's taking all the time between "Here's the path, now read the data."
- Is slow disk seek causing most of the delays because I'm reading so many files.

Directory traversal, without any other action, is "fast-enough", so just creating the NSURLs or file paths doesn't appear to be that problematic.

**Test setup:**

- 90,000 photos that are a mix of JPEGs and RAW files, as you would expect from years of amateur photography.

**Results:**

Instruments shows that I'm spending most of my time decoding JPEG headers, but that cumulative time is a fraction of the total time spent traversing all the files. The conclusion being that most of the time is being spent somewhere else and that somewhere else is in the file system.

Any help or tips on how to better benchmark what macOS is doing at the file system level such that I could squeeze out every last bit of performance would be appreciate.

Comment: Are you using the Record Waiting Threads option for the Time Profiler instrument? That shows where threads are spending their wall-clock time, not just CPU time. So, if they are blocked in a `read()` call, it will attribute that time to the `read()` call and the code path leading to it.

Comment: That helps a little bit. `fread` in `libsystem_c` now comes up and has a good chunk of time associated with it. In the trace, alongside the data for `Main Thread` there's two rows for `_pthread_wqthread` and one of them is taking a ton of time as well. Its call stack is only three deep and ends with `_workq_kernreturn`. Something kernel/IO related I presume. In a 50 second capture, there's still about 20 seconds unaccounted for in the profile. (i.e. I captured for 50 seconds but the sum of the traces is only 31 seconds.) Maybe that's normal as I'm not used to such precise measuring.

Comment: When using Record Waiting Threads, all threads will "take a ton of time". They exist, therefore they're included in the sample. (They can't be excluded for not using CPU time because you've told the instrument not to.) If the call tree for a thread is basically one straight line down to a wait-for-something-to-do function, then you can basically ignore it. Not sure about the missing time. You shouldn't add together the time for different threads. They're running simultaneously to each other, so it's the same time. Are you sure you haven't selected/filtered to a subset of samples?

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up Ken. I need to take a bit more time and investigate this some more (and maybe re-watch the WWDC video on profiling).